# Breadcrumb Navigation for Subfolder level

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-extensions, breadcrumb

I have the breadcrumb installed in the site which shows the root/parent folder of the library, i was wondering how to achieve the sub folders level of the folders of the breadcrumb navigation.

Reference of the breadcrumb https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-extensions/blob/main/samples/react-application-breadcrumb